# Find the Probability that three vertices chosen in a regular polygon with 9 vertices forms an isosceles triangle

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I started by taking two cases
(i) Pure isosceles(not equilateral): $E_1$  , and
(ii) Equilateral Triangle : $E_2$

---

**For finding Number of cases in $(E_1)$:**
[image]

Take any point as reference (Let's say 1) -- $\big(\binom{9}{1}$ ways $\big)$
and draw a line through this point and the centre of the polygon (red line in the figure). Now we select any one point from {2,3,5} -- $\big(\binom{3}{1}$ ways $\big)$
and include it's mirror (8) as well. -- (1 way only)
Hence the triangle we get (1-3-8) is a pure isosceles triangle.

Number of ways for this: $$\binom{9}{1}.\binom{3}{1}=27$$

**For finding Number of cases in $(E_2)$:**
only 3 equilateral triangles can be formed (1-4-7), (2-5-8), (3-6-9)  -- 3

---

Hence, total favourable cases: 30

Also, total ways to select any 3 vertices from 9 : $\binom{9}{3}=84$

Hence the Probability we should get is: $$\frac{27+3}{84}=\frac{5}{14}$$

---

But the book says it's $\frac{3}{7}$  I have tried going through my approach several times but can't find where I went wrong. Would appreciate if someone could help me out and even give a better way to approach this.

Comment: The book is wrong. It simply counts $4$ triangles for each vertex and hence $36$, without realizing that in case of equilateral triangles, it is just $3$ triangles in total and not $9$.